# How to keep a variable from changing in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to keep the original information of a variable so that a reset of the code will be much easier.

```
var $dataSets = [1,2,3,4];
var $oldData = $dataSets;

$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $dataSets.splice(1,1);
        console.log($dataSets);
    } else {
        console.log($oldData);
    }
});
```

The problem I have with my code is that when I modify `$dataSets` it also changes `$oldData`. How do I keep `$oldData` from changing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change to

```
 var $dataSets = [1,2,3,4];
 var $oldData = $dataSets.slice();
```

JavaScript does not pass the value of `$dataSets` into `$oldData`, rather it passes a reference to the thing which `$dataSets` itself references.

This workaround works because JavaScript's Arrays (which is what `$dataSets` is) have a method called `slice` which, when called with no parameters, returns a copy of the array.

Comment: You should probably include some info about _why_ this works.  Assigning one variable to another copies a reference to the underlying object.  .slice() creates a copy of the array.

Comment: @MikeEdwards I took care of it in my edit while you were commenting. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.slice()`, like this:

```
var $dataSets = [1,2,3,4];
var $oldData = $dataSets.slice();
```

As described in the documentation, `slice()`  does not alter the original array, but returns a new one. So basically, using slice, you have two different arrays, and can insert/remove items in one without interfering with the other.